# What is the equivalent of CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER on C#?

Tags: c#, curl

When I use curl in PHP, I can do

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Which allows me to store the result in a variable.

But C#'s [libcURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/dotnet/) doesn't have a return transfer option. What I can use instead of it on c#?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the equivalent has to be coded like this for example :

```
WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
String response = null;
using(var strReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```